# ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(...) getting stuck

Tags: java, io, objectoutputstream

I have a homework assignment, and it's getting stuck on ObjectOutputStream (initiated with a FileOutputStream) when it calls the writeObject(...) method. The object is a HashMap. I copied the 2 lines of the writeObject code from the example my professor gave me and it gives me the "uses unchecked or unsafe operations" warning, and it gets stuck, on the writeObject; neither happen in the professor's code.

```
     import java.io.FileInputStream;
     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
     import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
     import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
     import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
     import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
     import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
     import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
     import javax.swing.JLabel;
     import javax.swing.JButton;
     import javax.swing.JTextField;
     import java.awt.FlowLayout;
     import javax.swing.JFrame;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.util.Map;
     import java.util.HashMap;
     import java.io.FileReader;
     import java.io.BufferedReader;

     class ScrabbleWords
     {
        Map<String,Integer> secondHashMap = null;

        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
           new ScrabbleWords();
        }

        public ScrabbleWords()
        {
           BufferedReader br = null;
           BufferedReader brValues = null;
           try
           {
              br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt"));
              brValues = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ScrabbleLetterValues.txt"));
           }
           catch(FileNotFoundException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
           String nextLine = "";
           Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
           Map<Character,Integer> values = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
           try
           {
              for(int i = 0; (nextLine = brValues.readLine())!=null; i++)
              {
                 String[] splitStr = nextLine.split(",");
                 values.put(Character.toLowerCase(splitStr[0].charAt(0)),Integer.parseInt(splitStr[1]));
              }
              while((nextLine = br.readLine())!=null)
              {
                 int value = 0;
                 for(char c: nextLine.toCharArray())
                 {
                    value += values.get(Character.toLowerCase(c));
                 }
                 map.put(nextLine,value);
              }
              br.close();
              brValues.close();
           }
           catch(IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

           try
           {
              ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Scrabble_Hash_Map.dat",true));
              output.writeObject(map);
              System.out.println("boo!");
              output.close();

              ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Scrabble_Hash_Map.dat"));
              Object obj = input.readObject();
              if(obj instanceof HashMap) secondHashMap = (HashMap)obj;
              else throw new RuntimeException("Input File did not contain instance of HashMap for deserialization.");
              input.close();
           }
           catch(IOException|ClassNotFoundException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

           JFrame fr = new JFrame();
           fr.setTitle("Scrabble Word Value Look-Up");
           fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(fr.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           fr.setSize(300,100);
           fr.setLocation(300,300);
           fr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

           JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
           JButton btn = new JButton("Look-Up");
           JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("The Value Is: ");
           JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel();

           fr.add(field);
           fr.add(btn);
           fr.add(lbl1);
           fr.add(lbl2);

           field.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
           {
              public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
              {
                 if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_ENTER)
                 {
                    btn.doClick();
                    field.requestFocus();
                 }
              }
           });
           btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
           {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
                 int value = -1;
                 if(secondHashMap.get(field.getText())!=null) value = secondHashMap.get(field.getText().toLowerCase());
                 lbl2.setText((value < 0? "Word Not Found":String.valueOf(value)));
              }
           });

           //set window visible
           fr.setVisible(true);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Re `"Read this first: Every time I ask a question here, I get voted down, so I'm going to ask that you PLEASE don't because down-votes cause me to get suspended from asking further questions."` -- the solution to this is not to post this comment, but to strive to ask well constructed questions. If you haven't yet done so, do go through the [tour], the [help] sections and the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: Also look at [Jon Skeet's StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). It's an abbreviated version of his wonderful longer post on [Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: However in this case, it looks like a good question.

Comment: To improve it though, 1) divide and conquer: separate the I/O code from the GUI and test, enhance and debug them separately. Then if you have a bug, you can show only relevant code and not a lot of code completely irrelevant to your problem. 2) you state that you have a problem (other than the warning) where code "doesn't work". Please elaborate on that -- exactly *how* is it not working?

Comment: *and it gets stuck, on the writeObject;* - - what do you mean by `stuck` - Is this observed in a debugger?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: maybe that's where he got the down-votes from -- from not responding to comments in a timely way. We'll see, and I'm going to reserve judgement.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, I was just feeling the same.

Comment: Your error handling is **horrendous**! Calling `printStackTrace()` then continuing as if nothing when wrong. *Yikes!* For code like this, on error, print it **and exit**. Or don't `catch` exceptions, but let them bubble up out of `main()` and the JVM will print and exit for you.

Comment: @Andreas: at least the catch blocks are not empty. Lord knows we see too much of that -- that Java equivalent of driving your car with your eyes closed.

Comment: Appending to a file created with `ObjectOutputStream` isn't going to work anyway. It is difficult if not impossible to believe in this problem. I/O to a disk file doesn't block for long.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Not everyone can respond immediately. And that has nothing to do with the question I asked.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It gets stuck = it doesn't execute anything after that line of code. Same thing happens on debugger. I can say that it doesn't create the file though.

Comment: are you sure that you are using this code?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes? Why do you think I wouldn't be?

Comment: because sometimes peoples code does not get built/deployed correctly. See the comment by EJP above

Comment: @EJP I got rid of the "true" parameter in the method, and let it run for 17 minutes and it was still stuck.